# How can an integration on a transcendental equation's root be transformed into the equation itself?

Tags: integration, roots, dirac-delta

Given an integration like,
$$
\int_{b_1}^{b_2} g(x^*(b))~ \mathrm{d}b
$$
Where, $x^*(b)$ is a solution of $f(x)=b$. **How to reduce the integration in terms of the $f(x)-b$?**

### My attempt

\begin{align}
&\int_{b_1}^{b_2} g(x^*(b))~ \mathrm{d}b \tag{1}\label{1}\\
&=\int_{b_1}^{b_2} \left[ \int_{x^*(b)^-}^{{x^*(b)^+}} \mathrm{d}y ~ \delta(y - x^*(b)) \right] g(y)~ \mathrm{d}b \tag{2}\label{2}\\
&=\int_{b_1}^{b_2} \mathrm{d}b ~\left[ \int_{x^*(b)^-}^{{x^*(b)^+}} \mathrm{d}y ~ 
\frac{\delta(y - x^*(b))}{|{f'(x^*(b))}|} 
\right] |{f'(x^*(b))}|~ g(y) \tag{3}\label{3}\\
&=\int_{b_1}^{b_2} \mathrm{d}b \left[ \int_{x^*(b)^-}^{{x^*(b)^+}} \mathrm{d}y ~ 
\frac{\delta(y - x^*(b))}{|{f'(x^*(b))}|} |{f'(y)}| 
\right] g(y) \tag{4}\label{4} \\
&=\int_{b_1}^{b_2} \mathrm{d}b \left[ \int_{x^*(b)^-}^{{x^*(b)^+}} \mathrm{d}y ~ 
\delta(f(y) - b)|{f'(y)}| 
\right] g(y) \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{align}

In Eq. \eqref{4} I have used the fact $\int dx~\delta(x-y) h(x) = \int dx~\delta(x-y) h(y)$.
Is this the correct way to do this? Are there any alternative ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try with $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ and $x=f(y)$:

$$\int g(f^{-1}(x))dx=\int g(y)d(f(y))$$

Or rewrite as:

$$\int g(f^{-1}(x))dx=\int g(y)f’(y)dy,y=f^{-1}(x)$$

Now you have an integral with no inverse function in terms of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. You could use integration by parts:

$$\int g(f^{-1}(x))dx\mathop=^{y=f^{-1}(x)}\int g(y)d(f(y))=f(y)g(y)-\int f(y)d(g(y))=f(y)g(y)-\int f(y)g’(y)dy$$

if one derivative is easier than the other.

Comment: This is indeed nice. I have one question though; in the last line after doing the integration by parts, you get the term $f(y)g(y)$, do you assume them to be zero at the boundary? and is the sign in the last expression correct? (shouldn't there be a -ve sign?)

Comment: @Galilean It was a typo. Let me edit and thanks